# How Can I get the First and last name from users in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So how would I do this? Basically I have a list of patients in the firestore. I want to read from the list of patients and populate them into something on the website. But I'm unsure of how to do so.

```
<v-autocomplete
    :items="patients"
    :filter="customFilter"
    color="blue"
    v-model="selectedPatient"
    label="Select a patient to send report to"
></v-autocomplete>

db.collection('users').where("usertype", "==", "Patient")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const users = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
      this.patients = users;
    })
```

I'm not sure how to get it working. attempted this but it doesn't really work. So I iterate through the docs and then save it to patients value when then populates the autocomplete tag. But it only shows up as object object.

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 1):

If depends a bit on what the field names are in your database, but say they are `firstName` and `lastName`, then you could get those in the dropdown with:

```
const users = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
  return { doc.data().firstName + " " + doc.data().lastName };
})
```